# vibed: How can I handle POST request?

Tags: post, d, vibed

Could anybody help me to handle POST request, I read [docs](http://vibed.org/api/vibe.http.server/HTTPServerRequest), but it's not clear to me, how to handle POST request, that I send from page, to vibed server.

I wrote next code:

```d
import vibe.d;
import std.stdio;

void main()
{

    auto router = new URLRouter;
    router.any("*", &accControl);
    router.any("/my", &action);

    auto settings = new HTTPServerSettings;
    settings.port = 8080;
    settings.bindAddresses = ["::", "127.0.0.1"];

    listenHTTP(settings, router);
    runEventLoop();
}

void accControl(HTTPServerRequest req, HTTPServerResponse res)
{
    res.headers["Access-Control-Allow-Origin"] = "*";
}


void action(HTTPServerRequest req, HTTPServerResponse res)
{
    // how get string from POST request here. And how get JSON object, if server send it.
}
```

but what method I should use for req? As I understand expect POST body there is sending a lot of other data.

The POST request is sending with JQuery:

```js
$.post("http://127.0.0.1:8080", "\"answers_result\":777");
```

So I need to get this JSON and send with vibed it's to DB. But problem that I can't understand how to handle it.

Comment: FYI `std.stdio.writeln` is part of blocking I/O. You should not use it inside event loop.

Comment: I should point out that `"\"answers_result\":777"` is invalid JSON. You probably meant `"{\"answers_result\":777}"`.

Comment: JS tip: use single quotation mark. E.g. `'{"answers_result": 777}'` — see? There's no need to escape `"`.

Comment: @sigrod, thanks for tip!
But what in Chrome console I see string with quoter marks before first and after last element of answer? (--> `"{"QID ... `) and `90}"`
`["{"QID": 1, "AID": 5, "SubAID":[],"MinArea": 10, "MaxArea": 90}"]`

When I creating JSON string I do not have them:
`var answers_string = (`{"QID": question.id, "AID": _answer.id, "SubAID":[SubAID_val],`).replace("question.id", question.id).replace("_answer.id", _answer.id);  `

Comment: Why not just `JSON.stringify({ QID: question.id, AID: _answer.id, ... })`?

Comment: Thanks, I will try it now!

Comment: About Chrome console: it's just how console represents a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In main:

```d
auto router = new URLRouter;
router.post("/url_to_match", &action);

listenHTTP(settings, router);
```

Action:

```d
void action(HTTPServerRequest req, HTTPServerResponse res)
{
    auto answers_result = req.json["answers_result"].to!int;

    // ...
}
```

Or you can use [`registerRestInterface`](http://vibed.org/api/vibe.web.rest/registerRestInterface).

Comment: Could you show what function should be in `action() {}`, I do not understand how to extract request.

Comment: Thans, but why I see in Log of Chrome `POST http://127.0.0.1:8080/my 404 (Not Found)`
I thought if server start I should see status `200`

Comment: @user1432751 Did you configured your router? E.g. `router.post("/my", &action);`

Comment: I updated my example in start topic to my present code.
In example you are specified name if incoming data, but what if I do not know this name?
Could you also show how to handle simple text, not json

Comment: @user1432751 You can use [`Json`](http://vibed.org/api/vibe.data.json/Json) API to full extend, I've just provided usage example.

Comment: @user1432751 Then you need to use [`HTTPServerRequest.bodyReader`](http://vibed.org/api/vibe.http.server/HTTPServerRequest.bodyReader), but read documentation carefully.

Comment: thanks I will try to understand docs, but I can't understand why I am getting `404` error.
And I would be very pleased if you will explain what should I do if I do not name of element that is coming to server. In your example it's named "answers_result" --> `req.json["answers_result"].to!int;`

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example code to show how to read POST params from vibe.d:

Main Function:

```
shared static this()
{
   auto router = new URLRouter;
   router.post("/url_to_match", &action);

   auto settings = new HTTPServerSettings;
   settings.port = 3000;
   listenHTTP(settings, router);
}
```

Action:

```
void action(HTTPServerRequest req, HTTPServerResponse res)
{
    // Read first POST parameter named "first_name"
    auto firstName = req.form["first_name"];

    // Read second POST parameter named "last_name"
    auto lastName = req.form["last_name"];

    // Prepare output to be sent to client.
    auto name = "Hello %s, %s".format(lastName, firstName);

    // Send data back to client
    res.writeBody(name);
}
```

Build the program and run it, to try it out on your local machine you may execute the following simple curl request:

```
curl --data "first_name=kareem&last_name=smith" "http://localhost:3000/url_to_match"
```

HTH